# Restart Python Program after user changes

Tags: python

In my program, I have a config `file` which gets read on initialization and sets certain runtime `variables`. While the program is running a user can access and change these `values` in the config `file` through a menu I've created. Once these `values` have been modified I need the program to shut down and restart, so that it can run with the new config `values`.

I'm programming this in python and I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Please post your attempts so far to solve this problem, and then explain what the error with your code is. This website is not here to write code for you, it is to give you advice and help on code that you have already written but needs more work.

Comment: Just re-read the file again to get the new changes

Answer (score 1):

You can either set a `method` to read the `file` for the new `variables` without restarting, or you can use

```
def restart_program():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582604/restart-my-program-in-python)

Comment: I would just reread and change the variables, if those vriables weren't passed to create objects that are running the rest of the program.  But thank you for the code snippet, I'll give it a test and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sys.exit() to terminate the running process, but your best option is probably just to re-intialize/read files rather than terminating your code and restarting (i.e., you could call main() again).
Hope this helps.